# Adding rows to a table, looping an array, doing crazy things, readding first row each time

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, html-table, local-storage

I feel like this is probably an issue with the loop somewhere, but I am a bit newer to coding and I am having trouble figuring out where exactly the issue is.
Every time I add a new task to the list, it prints the first task again. So if i add a second task, it inserts the first task and second task into the table, if i add a third task it inserts the first task and third task into the table.. its weird.

I looked in my local storage files, and its being stored properly. as in, (task one, task two, task three) no repetition there and its getting stored the way I want it to.

The issue is I am trying to do this:

I want to loop through the array, and have everything that is stored in local storage be posted on the table. (Currently, when I refresh it resets completely. its acting like session storage rather than local storage. it shows up in local storage after I refresh, but as soon as I click to add more after the refresh it disappears)
its a to do list, so I want it to basically show all items by looping through the array, and when I add a new item, have it store that and loop through the array again and post it on the table.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableBody");

toDoArray = [];


function buildTable(){
addToStorage();
var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;


  for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
    var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
    var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
    var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
    cellName.innerHTML= parsedObject[i].name;
    cellDate.innerHTML= parsedObject[i].date;
    var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
    cellCheck.innerHTML = checkStuff;
  }


}

function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      buildTable();
};

function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}

function addToStorage(){
  var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
  localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);}
```

Comment: could you add your html also

Comment: Declaring `i` in `buildTable` function might help?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling buildTable in submit form, its looping over the whole array again and adding the elements to table. Try this,

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableBody");

toDoArray = [];


function buildTable(){
addToStorage();
var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;

for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
  addTaskToTable(parsedObject[i]);
}



}

function addTaskToTable(obj){
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
  var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
  cellName.innerHTML= obj.name;
  cellDate.innerHTML= obj.date;
  var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
  cellCheck.innerHTML = checkStuff;

}

function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      addTaskToTable(taskSomething);
};

function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}

function addToStorage(){
  var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
  localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);
  }
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Or still not able to proceed?

Comment: that solved the issue! thank you! now how would I go about having the saved table load after the refresh? call one of the functions I have on there already onload or do i need to create a new function ? (that seems like it would mess it up...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet with my comments.

```js
var tasksStorageName = 'myTasks';
var tasksTable = document.getElementById("tasks_table");
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save_task_btn");
var tasksList;
var storage = getStorage();

// this is dirty workaround, because localStorage disabled
// due to security reasons. feel free to remove this function
// and use localStorage directly
function getStorage() {
  try {
    return window.localStorage;
  }
  catch(e) {
    return {
      get: function(key) {
        return JSON.stringify([
          {
            id: Date.now(),
            name: 'first task',
            date: '10/10/2016',
            done: false
          }
        ]);
      },
      set: function(key, object) {

      }
    };
  }
}

function getTasksList() {
  var dumpedTasks = storage.get(tasksStorageName);
  
  // in case there are no tasks saved we return empty list
  // otherwise parse our tasks.
  return dumpedTasks == null ? [] : JSON.parse(dumpedTasks);
}

function dumpTaskList(tasksList) {
  var dumpedTasks = JSON.stringify(tasksList);
  
  storage.set(tasksStorageName, dumpedTasks);
}

// try to reuse things, so we have `renderTasks` function
// to render all our tasks to table which uses `renderTask`
// for each task. later we'll use it to add our newly created
// tasks.
function renderTasks(tasks) {
  for (var index = 0; index < tasks.length; index++) {
    var task = tasks[index];
    
    renderTask(task);
  }
}

// helper function to create checkbox
function createCheckboxForTask(task){
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input'); 
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.checked = task.done;
    
    return checkbox;
}

function renderTask(task) {
  var taskRow = tasksTable.insertRow();
  var doneCell = taskRow.insertCell();
  var nameCell = taskRow.insertCell();
  var dateCell = taskRow.insertCell();
  
  taskRow.id = task.id;
  doneCell.appendChild(createCheckboxForTask(task));
  nameCell.innerText = task.name;
  dateCell.innerText = task.date;
}

function createTask(name, date) {
  return {
    // quite naive id generation, don't use it in production
    id: Date.now(),
    name: name,
    date: date,
    done: false
  }
}

// to restore your previously added tasks
// you need to get them from localStorage
// on load event and render them.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  tasksList = getTasksList();
  
  if (tasksList.length > 0) {
    renderTasks(tasksList);
  }
});

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("task_name").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("task_date").value;
  var newTask = createTask(name, date);
  
  tasksList.push(newTask);
  renderTask(newTask);
  dumpTaskList(tasksList);
});
/*
// function does too many things
function buildTable(){
// if you try to call `buildTable` at page load then
// `addToStorage` function will set localStorage task item
// to empty array. thats why you lost your state every time
// you reload page
addToStorage();
var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
// why this two unnecessary variables?
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;

for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
  addTaskToTable(parsedObject[i]);
}



}

// try to give parametes as well as variables meaningful names
// like `task` this time, not `obj`
function addTaskToTable(obj){
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
  var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
  cellName.innerHTML= obj.name;
  cellDate.innerHTML= obj.date;
  var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
  cellCheck.innerHTML = checkStuff;

}

function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      addTaskToTable(taskSomething);
};

// actually you are creating new task object, not getting it
// from somewhere, so it's better to name it like createTask
// or newTask
function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}

function addToStorage(){
  var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
  localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);
  }
  */
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input id="task_name" type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Date: </label>
  <input id="task_date" type="text"/>
</div>
<button id="save_task_btn" type="button">Save</button>
<table id="tasks_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
<table>
```